# fio benchmark configuration

Tags: linux, io, benchmarking

I'm doing some I/O tests with different benchmarks and I want to compare the results; in detail, I'm using `sysbench` and `fio` and doing random read/write tests.
With sysbench i have a read/write ratio of 1.50 and a total number of requests of 10000 (6000 reads and 4000 writes).
How can I repeat the same configuration for fio?
On linux man pages I found that the default ratio is 50:50 and there are two parameters:

```
rwmixread (default 50)
rwmixwrite (default 50)
```

that can be set to modify it.
So can I set them to 60 and 40 respectively to do what I want?

What about the total number of requests instead? I can't find something helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This might be better aimed at the [fio mailing list](https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/fio-2.17/README#L77) but try looking at the [`number_ios`](http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-number_ios) parameter to control total number of I/Os. As you suggested the [`rwmixread`](http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-rwmixread) parameter should be enough to change the ratio when using `read=rw`.